# How to represent OR table using JOIN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query having 4 tables `Table1`, `Table2`, `Table3` and `Table4`.

`Table1` is master table having IDs
`Table2` is child table with FK relationship with `Table1` and has a column called `Tag`.
`Table3` is child table with FK relationship with `Table1` and has a column called `Code`
`Table4` is child table with FK relationship with `Table1` and has column called `Code2`

Now I want a query to represent follow logic

```
Select Table1.ID 
From Table1 ...
WHERE Table2.Tag IN( 1,2,3,4)
      AND ( Table3.Code In (456,789) OR Table4.CODE2 in (123,897) )
```

I know I can have join between `Table1` and `Table2` get the ids for which `Tag` value is in `(1,2,3,4)`. But I am not sure how to join the `Table3` and `Table4` to achieve the requirement.

Comment: you said both table3/table4 have FK relationship with table1. Then join on that column which referencing table1. Else, show your table schema for table3 and table4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just keep adding joins to the child table based on the condition that the Foreign Key column in each child table equals the key of Table1

You're query should look like this

```
Select Table1.ID 
From Table1 
JOIN Table2 ON Table2.FK_ID = Table1.ID 
JOIN Table3 ON Table3.FK_ID = Table1.ID 
JOIN Table4 ON Table4.FK_ID = Table1.ID 
WHERE Table2.Tag IN( 1,2,3,4)
AND ( Table3.Code In (456,789) OR Table4.CODE2 in (123,897) )
```

But with FK_ID replaced with the appropriate Foreign Key field

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I Will try this and let you know.